# Does substitution model require an environment

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am writing a tiny evaluator for Scheme.

I need to write the evaluator with substitution model, therefore no assignments like `set!` are to be used.

But since I still need to store primitive procedures and user-`define`d variable in some place, do I need an environment? If so, what is the difference between substitution model and environment model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No -- for a plain substitution-based evaluator you do *not* need an environment.  This is because as soon as you have a binding (eg, when you perform a function call) you immediately substitute the name with the value, so there is no need to keep the name->value mapping around.  In fact, you can view an environment as a way to avoid the overhead involved with substitutions by caching them and performing them later instead.  See [PLAI](http://www.plai.org/) for a textbook that follows this view -- in fact, it goes from substitutions to *substitution caches*, and only later does it change the terminology to *environments*.

But note that the issue of using `set!` is unrelated to all of this.  When you consider `set!`, you first need to be clear on what level of `set!` you're talking about: if it's in the language that you're *implementing* rather than in the implementation itself, then it's possible to add that given any kind of a mutable value -- for example, in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) you can use [boxes](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/boxes.html) and that's enough for implementing `set!` in the language.  This is traditionally done in an environment-based evaluator, where the environment type is changed from mapping names to values to mapping names to *locations* (implemented as boxes or a similar mutable value).  But that's not really necessary: you can still do that with a substitution-based evaluator where these boxes are becoming part of the domain of values that you're substituting.  To give a concrete example, you could start with an expression like (using a scheme-like language):

```
(let ((x 1))
  (begin (set! x 2)
         (set! x 3)))
```

and instead of substituting `1` for `x` you would allocate a box holding `1`, then substitute that *same* box resulting in

```
(begin (set! #<box> 2)
       (set! #<box> 3))
```

where the two `#<box>`es are that single box.  (Note that this is not implementation code that I'm talking about, but expressions in the language that you're evaluating.)  The reason that this is not usually done is that it can be confusing -- you need to represent values as boxes that can be substituted, those boxes are not something that is part of the source user program yet they are values that the interpreter should deal with (eg, the last `#<box>` is the return value -- but it's the value that you want to return, not the box), and you need to be careful about box identity (eg, it is important for the two boxes in the above to be the *same* box for the interpretation of the first `set!` to be visible in the second).

So doing this is not recommended if you're just learning about writing interpreters.  If this is the case, then I suggest you just look in that textbook.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It seems that the “environment” for substitution model is merely a terminology issue. I will read PLAI for more information.

Comment: No, the environment is -- always -- a mapping between names (identifiers) and values.  In the substitution model there is no need for this, since values are immediately replaced in the body.

Comment: I finished the evaluator after reading PLAI and another related book and I realized that you are right. Thanks for these detailed information.

Comment: Whew...  (I don't care much for the SO game, but it bugged me that there were wrong questions about this...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you still need an environment because like you said you need to be able to store variables and such.

The substitution model is a way to help you see how a given procedure will be evaluated.  For example, you can define the square function

`(define (square x) (* x x))`

With the substitution model, if you called

```
(square 4)
```

then you substitute the 4 into every occurrence of x in your function definition so

```
(* 4 4) => 16
```

The environment is used for you to visualise how variables and state are stored in your interpreter.  So in a nutshell, the substitution model is used for helping you evaluate procedures while the environment is used to see how your interpreter will remember the variables and definitions that a user may define when they use your interpreter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And I want to ask that are these two models useful only when demonstrating how a calculation is completed? For me it seems that they are both used in the eval/apply loop.

Comment: I think the substitution model is more used for demonstrating how a calculation is completed.  The environment model is a way the interpreter will store state.  For example, a procedure call will make its own environment that will extend the global environment and hold its own variables.